# there exists no non vanishing vector field on $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

How can I prove that there exists no non vanishing vector field on $S^2$. I know there is a general theorem, called "Hairy Ball Theorem". But since I am a beginner, I have not yet studied all the things which are needed for the proof of Hairy Ball Theorem. I have studied basics of manifold, smooth maps, tangent spaces, homotopy theory. Is there any proof based on these topics. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes there is for the smooth case. Compute the degree of the map $f \colon S^n \to S^n$ given by $$f(p) = -p.$$ Show that if $S^n$ admits a nonvanishing smooth vector field, then $f$ is smoothly homotopic to the identity, and therefore $f$ has degree $1$. You will see that $f$ does not have degree $1$ when $n$ is even, so a smooth nonvanishing vector field cannot exist on $S^n$ when $n$ is even.

Comment: There is also a completely elementary proof by Milnor in "Analytic proofs of the hairy ball theorem".

Comment: One can do a basic proof without degree theory just using Stokes's Theorem. One still needs to know that homotopic maps preserve the integrals of closed forms.